# Autoadd account after application is installed

Tags: android, accountmanager

Is there any way to add automatically account just after installation my application (but it was not started yet).

Comment: YOu need to be more specific as what you are trying to do. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to do *anything* "just after installation my application (but it was not started yet)". When the user launches your main activity, you can set up the account or whatever other sort of first-time event you want.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a peace of code which automatically activates account

```
    final AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
    String authority = getString(R.string.acc_authority);
    String accountType = getString(R.string.acc_name);
    String accountName = getString(R.string.app_name);

    Account[] existingAccs = accountManager.getAccountsByType(accountType);
    if (existingAccs.length > 0) {
        return;
    }

    Account account = new Account(accountName, accountType);
    if (accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, null, null)) {
        ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, authority, 1);
        ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, authority, true);
        ContentResolver.requestSync(account, authority, new Bundle());
        ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account, authority, new Bundle(), 60*10);
    }
```

Comment: Currently after install my app and login I have to go to Accounts to enable the sync. By default it's off. Is there any way that I can set default on?